# H2 blocking when using multiple threads to read data

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, h2

My application is having performance problems when multiple HTTP requests come at the same time.

Env:

```
Spring Boot: 2.4.2
H2: 1.4.199

url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOG=0;CACHE_SIZE=131072;LOCK_MODE=0;UNDO_LOG=0;AUTOCOMMIT=TRUE
```

The application for each rest API GET will create multiple threads that run separately and are joined in the end.

There are a lot of SELECTs being done in each thread, read-only.

In total in a single request, there may be from 1500 to 2000 queries.

If a request comes, it is handled very well and the response time is usually between 0.5s - 2s.

If you send 5 requests simultaneously, the application goes deadlocked. All requests will have around the same response time from 8-10 seconds.

Each request might have around 40-80 threads.

From the profiler, the threads are blocked at `CacheLongKeyLIRS` and from the IntelliJ profiler, the `MVStore` seems to be using the most CPU.

Does anyone know any optimization that can be done to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You should try to use the latest version of H2 first, there were various scalability improvement since 1.4.199.

Comment: Tried that and the exact deadlock happens. Using version 2.1.214